# Jewish History Timeline

Tags: history

I am looking specifically to pinpoint when the purim story began, and how close that was in relation to the destruction of the first beis hamikdash.

Comment: https://embassies.gov.il/UnGeneva/AboutIsrael/history/Pages/History-Israel-Timeline.aspx https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3915966/jewish/Timeline-of-Jewish-History.htm

Comment: Most timelines you see around are the opinion of particular aggadic midrash called "Seder Olam" but many rishonim and acharonim have quibbled with various parts depending on which other Midrashim you accept or not. So good luck pinpointing.

Comment: @DoubleAA Unfortunately my knowledge of the jewish historical timeline is not very good. I am trying to pinpoint the timeline between the destruction of the first beis hamikdash and the beginning of the purim story. Was the exiling of mordechai by nebuchadnezzar related to the events of the destruction of bayis rishon? Unfortunately, jewish history is not my strong point...from my reading, the destruction had been only 57 years prior to purim story - is that really accurate?

Comment: To the question you raised in your comment: Of course it was. All of Nebuchadnezzar's exiles were part of the Babylonian foreign policy of exiling rebellious vassal nations. Mordechai or one of his ancestors was part of the Jeconiah exile, after Jeconiah attempted to rebel against the Babylonians. Jeconiah was replaced by  his uncle Zedikiah but eventually also rebelled. That was the final straw that led to the conquest of Jerusalem, its destruction along with the temple and the exile of the rest (or much of the rest; the subject is debatable) of the people of the Kingdom of Judah.

Comment: @Harel13 Wow, so when Ezra 2:2 mentions mordechai returning to jerusalam, t isnt the same mordechai from purim. And when darius eventually permitted the rebuilding, mordechai must have been extremely old. (ive got so many questions that keep multiplying, but im not sure this is the correct place to lay them all out)

Comment: I didn't say that, though indeed there is a disagreement regarding the identity of that Mordechai.

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you, this is very helpful and interesting.